# Toyota Yaris 2010 A/c problem

Tags: toyota, hvac

I have a weird problem with the A/C on my Toyota Yaris 2010. The A/c takes time to cool after being in the sun for a long time, and when the A/c does cool somewhat, it starts behaving weird. When the A/C is cooling (albeit bearly) and when I go around a curve, the A/C stops cooling. And when the A/C is not cooling, and I go over a speed bump, it starts cooling. The switch between cooling and non-cooling is not really consistent. It could be not-cooling at a standstill, and then starts cooling after I'm driving at speed, and viz. versa!. Any thoughts, please. My mechanic tells me its the compressor that needs replacing. Thanks.

Comment: Have you fixed it?